# MongoDB tags with key value pair search

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database-metadata

I have a mongo collection 'CARDS' having a list of tag objects. (kind of metadata)

```
"tags" : [
        {
            "tagValue" : "retail", 
            "tagName" : "CARD_TYPE"
        },
        {
            "tagValue" : "fast food ", 
            "tagName" : "CARD_SUB_TYPES"
        }, 
        {
            "tagValue" : "ghy", 
            "tagName" : "LOCATION"
        }, 
        {
            "tagValue" : "t1", 
            "tagName" : "LOCATION_AREA"
        }, 
        {
            "tagValue" : "guest", 
            "tagName" : "LOCATION_AREA_TYPE"
        }, 
        {
            "tagValue" : "departure", 
            "tagName" : "LOCATION_AREA_WAY"
        },
        { 
            "tagName" : 'CITY', 
            "tagValue" : 'delhi' 
        }
    ],
```

Now i want to search the documents from the collection based on those tags.
There may be any no of tag objects with a key(`tagName`) and value(`tagValue`). Also, there may be multiple doc with the same tagName with a different value.
I indexed the tags as `tags.tagName :1` and `tags.tagValue: 1`

Now I want to search from those tags with some tagName having values with some required  and some with optional
i.e. mixing of AND / OR
like where

```
{{tagName:LOCATION AND tagValue:ghy} AND {tagName:LOCATION_AREA AND tagValue:t1}}
OR {{tagName:CITY AND tagValue:delhi} AND { tagName: 'COUNTRY', tagValue: 'in' }}
OR { tagName: 'ANYTHING', tagValue: 'any_value' } ..
```

I queried for where all the required value must present as

> .find({   tags: {
>       $all: [
>         { $elemMatch: { tagName: 'LOCATION', tagValue: 'ghy' } },
>         { $elemMatch: { tagName: 'LOCATION_AREA', tagValue: 't1' } }
>       ]   } });

and tried this for optional

> .find({   tags: {
>       $elemMatch: {
>         $or: [
>           { tagName: 'CITY', tagValue: 'delhi' },
>           { tagName: 'COUNTRY', tagValue: 'in' }
>         ]
>       }   } });

Now not able to combine these two and to fulfill my requirements. I am new in MongoDB also the first project with mongo. Please help to achieve my requirement? OR any different strategy to achieve these.

Comment: In my first find query, I wanted to search all cards where LOCATION = 'ghy' and also LOCATION_AREA = 't1'. and the outcome was as expected.                           
Also , in second query I wanted to search all cards either having CITY = 'delhi' or 'country'='in' . the outcome also as expected. How to combine these two for now . ?

Answer (score 1):

if I understand the question correctly then Below query will help you what is your requirement.

```
db.things.find( {
      $and : [
               { 
                 $or : [ 
                         {"tagName" : "CITY", "tagValue" : "delhi"},
                         {"tagName": "COUNTRY", "tagValue" : "in" }
                       ]
               },
               { "tagName" : "COUNTRY", "tagValue" : "in" },
               {"tagName" : "LOCATION_AREA", "tagValue" : "t1"} 
             ]
    } )
```

Comment: Thank you , i will try this